# Subtract rows mysql from another row

Tags: mysql, timestamp, subquery

Below are my table content,

```
+---------------------+
| 2016-10-13 00:02:28 |
| 2016-10-13 00:12:27 |
| 2016-10-13 00:22:20 |
| 2016-10-13 00:12:05 |
| 2016-10-13 00:32:25 |
| 2016-10-13 00:34:05 |
| 2016-10-13 00:33:03 |
| 2016-10-13 00:45:06 |
| 2016-10-13 00:56:14 |
| 2016-10-13 00:42:22 |
```

How to subtract 2nd row with 1st, 4th with 3rd ? Basically I want to calculate time interval between these rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

`select a.order_id - (select b.order_id from sales_order_payment b where b.id = a.id + 1) from sales_order_payment a where a.id = 1823595234;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.datetime, a.id, ISNULL(b.datetime, 0) - a.datetime FROM YourTable AS a LEFT JOIN YourTable AS b ON a.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM YourTable WHERE id > a.id)
```

Comment: You should add some commentary to your answer that explains why it works.

Comment: sure @BrokenBinary I'll answer according to your suggestion in Future. Thank you